# Parsing XML child using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have below XML format

```
<Result>
    <system>
      <STATIC>
       <Tag1>2015-10-29T02:02:38-08:00</Tag1>
       <Tag2>264000000</Tag2>
       <Tag3>32696320</Tag3>
      </STATIC>
    </system>
</Result>
```

I have tried below code for parse child

```
 if(window.DOMParser)
 {
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(res,"text/xml");
 }
 else // Internet Explorer
 {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(res);
 }

var result=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Result"); // Result child
```

For system child

```
var system=result[0].childNodes[0];
```

But when i tried to get `<system>` tag child it gives me error

```
var staticResp=system[0].childNodes[0];
```

**error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined(…)**

So can you please help me how to get `<static>` child and it's value using tag name

---

Thank you Guys for quick reply

I have got above XML in ajax response. I have capture xml string using debugging tool I have see some special characters like `&#13;&#10;` after system tag

So I think your solutions not works for me

Please help me How to ignore this special character and get parsing string

Captured XML :

```
<Result><system>&#13;&#10; <STATIC>&#13;&#10; <Tag1>2015-10-29T02:02:38-08:00</Tag1>&#13;&#10; <Tag2>264000000</Tag2>&#13;&#10; <Tag3>32696320</Tag3></STATIC>&#13;&#10; </system></Result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.getElementsByTagName` and get tag by name without `childNodes`

```js
var xmlData = 
    '<Result>' + 
    '<system>' + 
    '<STATIC>' +
    '<Tag1>2015-10-29T02:02:38-08:00</Tag1>' +
    '<Tag2>264000000</Tag2>' + 
    '<Tag3>32696320</Tag3>' + 
    '</STATIC>' +
    '</system>' + 
    '</Result>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, 'text/xml');

var result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Result');

var static = xmlDoc
  .getElementsByTagName('system')[0]
  .getElementsByTagName('STATIC')[0];

console.log(static.getElementsByTagName('Tag1')[0].innerHTML);
console.log(static.getElementsByTagName('Tag2')[0].innerHTML);
console.log(static.getElementsByTagName('Tag3')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`system` is a single node and not an array of nodes. Try using

```
var staticResp = system.childNodes[0];
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/kevevovafi/edit?js,output)</kbd>

Comment: Working fine for me. Check the JSFiddle!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). What you can do is the following:

```
var staticResp = doc.getElementsByTagName('STATIC')[0];
```

```js
var xmlText = '<Result>\
    <system>\
      <STATIC>\
       <Tag1>2015-10-29T02:02:38-08:00</Tag1>\
       <Tag2>264000000</Tag2>\
       <Tag3>32696320</Tag3>\
      </STATIC>\
    </system>\
</Result>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "application/xml");
var staticResp = doc.getElementsByTagName('STATIC')[0];

for(var i = 0; i < staticResp.children.length; i++){
    snippet.log(staticResp.children.item(i).tagName);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```